# Hatcher $3.1.12$ Show that $H^k(X,X^n;G)=0$ for $k \leq n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In Hatcher it is written in a theorem that by Universal Coefficient Theorem we get $H^k(X,X^n;G)=0$ where $X,X^n$ are CW complexes. But to use UCT, we have to show $H_k(X,X^n;G)=0$ $k \leq n$. According to the question we can use the theorems for homology that $H_k(X^n)=0$ for $k>n$ and $H_k(X)=0$ if $k> dim(X)$.

Comment: Because $X^n$ is a subcomplex, you can apply one of Hatcher's corollaries of the excision theorem, whereby $H_k(X,X^n;G) = H_k(X/X^n;G)$. This latter has no cells of dimension between $1$ and $n$ inclusive, so cellular homology gives the desired result.

Comment: Ok then $H_k(X/X^n;G)=0$ for $0<k<n$ right? But $H_0(X,X^n)=?$ and $H_n(X,X^n)=?$

Comment: I think that would be no cell between $0$ and $n+1$ inclusive so $H_n(X,X^n)=0$ too..

Comment: Now what for $H_0(X,X^n)$?

Comment: $X / X^n$ is a wedge sum of spheres, so it's path-connected. What should $H_0(X / X^n)$ be in this case?

Comment: Ok thank you $H_k(X,X^n)= \widetilde H_k(X/X^n)$. So, $H_0(X,X^n)=0$

Comment: May I know why it is voted down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right: if you can show that $H_k(X,X^n;\mathbb Z)$ is trivial for $k\leq n$ you will be done, by applying the universal coefficient theorem.

We want to use that $X/X^n$ has only a point as $n-1$ skeleton, it is in particular connected. Because then we know by excision that $H_k(X,X^n) \cong \tilde H_k (X/X^n) =0$, since we know that cellular homology is the same as singular homology.

---

As a note on the (for simplicity non-relative) UCT: you have to read it right! You can consider just the version for abelian groups, i.e. $\mathbb Z$-modules, it will give you the exact sequence:
$$0\to Ext(H_{i-1}(X),G) \to H^i(X;G) \to Hom_{\mathbb Z} (H_i(X),G) \to 0.$$

Now if you want to change the underlying ring (which is here $\mathbb Z$) you have to use a PID and change the homology to $R$-modules. Why don't you have to do that anyways? Because you can define $H^i(X;G)$ without homology with coefficients. So also in particular $G$ is independent of the underlying ring you would choose in the more general UCT (of course the result depends).

Comment: I added a little note about the uct, which you seemed to interpret slightly wrong. So that explains, why you only need the triviality of $H_i(X)$.